# Sorting and Formatting with TableSorter

Tags: jquery, ajax, sorting, parsing, tablesorter

I'm trying to format some data of a table that is constantly updated by `ajax`.

I want that the float data 
become this

> 1.100.500,00 (currency)

after I sort it.

The problem is that `tablesorter` only sorts the float values correctly if they are in the first format. What I need to do is:

1. When `ajax` loads the data, show it like (currency), as currency.
2. When a `table <th>` is clicked to sort data, remove the (currency) currency format and sort the data correctly.
3. After sorted correctly, re-format the data like (currency), as currency.

I already tried this:( that I've found that it's the solution to many questions here in SO)

```
$.tablesorter.addParser({ 
        // set a unique id 
        id: 'thousands',
        is: function(s) { 
            // return false so this parser is not auto detected 
            return false; 
        }, 
        format: function(s) {
            // format your data for normalization 
            return s.replace('.','').replace(/,/g,'');
        }, 
        // set type, either numeric or text 
        type: 'numeric' 
        }); 


        $("#table_1").tablesorter({
            headers: {
                2: {//zero-based column index
                    sorter:'thousands'
                }
            }
    });
```

but it's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four things that fixing ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/bbxxomhx/39/)):

1. The function to replace periods will only remove one. So change it to `.replace(/\./g, "")` (the period needs to be escaped as well).
2. Remove the `$` from the string
3. Replace the `,` with a decimal point, so the value gets parsed correctly.
4. Convert the value from a string to a number using the built-in `$.tablesorter.formatFloat` function.

   ```
   $.tablesorter.addParser({
     id: 'thousands',
     is: function(s) {
       return false;
     },
     format: function(s) {
       var number = s.replace(/\$/g, '').replace(/\./g, '').replace(/,/g, '.');
       return $.tablesorter.formatFloat(number);
     },
     type: 'numeric'
   });
   $(function() {
     $("table").tablesorter({
       theme: 'blue',
       headers: {
         0: {
           sorter: 'thousands'
         }
       }
     });
   });
   ```

The demo I shared is using my [fork of tablesorter](https://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/), but the code will also work as expected in the original version.

Comment: I will try and tell the results

Comment: Hi, I updated the code but it didn't worked :( . One thing that I didn't understood in your Fiddle it's that the values on your HTML are already in the format that I want( 999.999,99), not in the format that I currently receive(999999.99). **EDIT** woops my bad. The code that you passed is a parser that is prepared to receive the values in that currency format, right?

Comment: Tested it again doing the right way, your answer worked. Thank you very much!